# Is every 1-Lipschitz homeomorphism $f:X\to X$ from a compact metric space to itself an isometry?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, compactness, isometries

I found a statement involving a homeomorphism $f:X\to X$ of a compact metric space $X$, with Lipshitz coefficient 1, i.e., a non-expansive map, and cannot think of an example where $f$ is not an isometry. Must it be?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12285/isometry-in-compact-metric-spaces

Comment: You are right, thanks! I can leave the question anyways in case someone else searches it using this phrasing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It follows from 1.6.15(1) in "A Course in Metric Geometry" by Burago, Burago, and Ivanov and 1.6.15(2) is a more general statement:

> Any distance-noncontracting map from a compact metric space to itself is an isometry.

This statement is needed in the proof that Gromov--Hausdorff metric is a metric.
Also check the solution of 1.12 in my ["Pure metric geometry"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.09846) it is based on a different idea.